# SFDX CLI and connection to second Playground

Tags: salesforcedx, cli

I want to experiment sfdx,so I'd like to link a playground I just created 
from my Trailhead (because I already linked my first playground)

The fact is, the password seems to be different from my first playground and this new one ??

I'm using :

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://brave-raccoon-362177-dev-ed.lightning.force.com -a "Playground 1 Brave Racoon"
```

This first playground (curious-moose-283525) works fine :
[image]

The commandline opens what you can see there :
[image]

Seems good to me, but the password isn't the same,
Am I missing something ?

Thansk !

EDIT :
I set a password for my playground, but got an error with port 1717.
I'll check furthermore for it later

[image]

Comment: Dev Hub is authorized (it's ok for other playgrounds, same trailhead account !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trailhead Playgrounds aren't scratch orgs linked to your Dev Hub. They're closer to independent Developer Editions.

To authorize them for use with Salesforce DX, you need to first [get your Trailhead Playground username and password](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/trailhead_playground_management/get-your-trailhead-playground-username-and-password). Each Playground will have an independent set of credentials. You can then authorize each Playground separately with

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -a MyPlayground
```

Comment: Thanks David !
I did it, but it seems I got an error with the port used ... 1717

I'm editing my post.
Think I'll restart my computer, because it's away of my knowledge.

Comment: This article should help me, I'll try !
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_troubleshoot_cancel_auth.htm

Comment: I think that error will resolve in a restart, @AlexisMASSON.